# Rails Gem does not set the setter method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I tried to put up a Ruby Gem based on Railscast Episode 033 Making a Plugin. I got the gem created and uploaded to Rubygems.org as `stringify-time`, but the setter method is not working.

[The GitHub Repo](https://github.com/the4dpatrick/stringify-time-gem)

The main part of the gem

```
module StringifyTime
  def stringify_time(*names)
    names.each do |name|
      define_method "#{name}_string" do
        read_attribute(name).to_s(:db) unless read_attribute(name).nil?
      end

      define_method "#{name}_string=" do |time_str|
        begin
          write_attribute("#{name}", Time.zone.parse(time_str))
        rescue ArgumentError
          instance_variable_set("@#{name}_invalid", true)
        end
      end

      define_method "#{name}_invalid?" do
        instance_variable_get("@#{name}_invalid")
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:extend, StringifyTime)
```

A attribute symbol is passed in and getter and setter methods are created. The getter method works, but when I try to update the attribute through the form, the data is not saved.

using the `stringify_time` method in the Task model

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base                                            
  validates_presence_of :name                                              
  stringify_time :due_at                                                   

  # def due_at_string                                                      
  #   due_at.to_s(:db)                                                     
  # end                                                                    

  # def due_at_string=(due_at_str)                                         
  #   self.due_at = Time.parse(due_at_str)                                 
  # rescue ArgumentError                                                   
  #   @due_at_invalid = true                                               
  # end                                                                    

  def validate                                                             
    errors.add :due_at, 'is invalid' if due_at_invalid? # @due_at_invalid  
  end                                                                      
end
```

When I uncomment the setter method I wrote manually, then I can edit the attribute.

Comment: Have you tried testing the generated methods from the Rails console? Also, there is quite some difference between the generated method and the hand-written one.

Answer (score 0):

Right after I tried to use the generated method in the rails console like @matjis-van-zuijlen suggested in the comments, I was able to update the `due_at` attribute. The issue was me not whitelisting `:due_at_string` in the controller.

```
def task_params                                                                                                                                       
  params.require(:task).permit(:name, :due_at, :due_at_string)                                                                                        
end
```